# Cannot deserialize Json from CouchDB

Tags: c#, json, .net, couchdb

i´m struggling with deserializing the Json i get.

It  looks like this:

```
{
    "seq": "13-g1AAAACLeJz",
    "id": "c32b670-37899h8c545",
    "changes": [
        {
            "rev": "9-68joc97b73df883a"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "seq": "15-g1AAAACLeJzLYWB-w",
    "id": "f73huvh3-of38j8fh",
    "changes": [
        {
            "rev": "4-10516b0f3"
        }
    ],
    "deleted": true
}
{
    "seq": "16-g1AAAACL4eJzL",
    "id": "M.Mustermann",
    "changes": [
        {
            "rev": "388-e6d350281"
        }
    ],
    "deleted": true
}
{
    "seq": "17-g1AAAACLr43_Q",
    "id": "f8h83hf-34f8h",
    "changes": [
        {
            "rev": "4-773re8f44e"
        }
    ],
    "deleted": true
}
{
    "seq": "18-g1AAwe_g",
    "id": "ewf/34r",
    "changes": [
        {
            "rev": "9-wehch87ewc"
        }
    ],
    "deleted": true
}
{
    "last_seq": "21-g1AA8wd998rAQ",
    "pending": 0
}
```

My Models:

```
public class Root    {
        public List<Result> results { get; set; } 
        public string last_seq { get; set; } 
        public int pending { get; set; } 
    }    

    public class Result
    {
        public string seq { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public List<Change> changes { get; set; }
        public bool? deleted { get; set; }
    }

    public class Change
    {
        public string rev { get; set; }
    }
```

I tried all the solutions i found but nothing works, i still get the following exception:

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: {. Path '', line 2, position 0.
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()

What i tried:

```
dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);

Root jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);

var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(json);
```

Comment: That isn't valid JSON, it looks like a series of JSON documents stuck together.

Comment: I think it is gonna be hard to deserialize that json without changing it. You've got a list of results which is not formatted as an array into your json and isn't comma separated. And it is followed by another object which isn't named and is different from the previous nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a series of JSON documents all stuck together. Also to make things even more awkward, the last one is different from the rest. So you need to parse them all manually and do some checking to see what kind of object you have. You can make use of the `JsonReader.SupportMultipleContent` property. For example, something like this:

```
//Somewhere to keep the parsed results
var results = new List<Result>();
Root root = null;

var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

using (var stringReader = new StringReader(Json))
using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader))
{
    //Make sure the JsonReader knows we have multiple documents
    jsonReader.SupportMultipleContent = true;

    while (jsonReader.Read())
    {
        //Read in the next document
        var nextObject = JObject.ReadFrom(jsonReader);

        //Determine if we are on the last item or not
        if(nextObject["last_seq"] != null)
        {
            root = nextObject.ToObject<Root>();
        }
        else
        {
            results.Add(nextObject.ToObject<Result>());
        }
    }
}

//Store the results in the root object since this is how your classes have been structured
if(root != null)
{
    root.results = results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this made my day. I now have data to work with.

Answer (score 0):

If you can ask for a change of the json you receive, the Json bellow should work.
If you can't, you will have to parse it yourself I think.

```
"results" : [{
"seq": "13-g1AAAACLeJz",
"id": "c32b670-37899h8c545",
"changes": [
    {
        "rev": "9-68joc97b73df883a"
    }
]
},
{
    "seq": "15-g1AAAACLeJzLYWB-w",
    "id": "f73huvh3-of38j8fh",
    "changes": [
        {
            "rev": "4-10516b0f3"
        } 
    ],
    "deleted": true
},
{
    "seq": "16-g1AAAACL4eJzL",
    "id": "M.Mustermann",
    "changes": [
        {
            "rev": "388-e6d350281"
        }
    ],
    "deleted": true
},
{
    "seq": "17-g1AAAACLr43_Q",
    "id": "f8h83hf-34f8h",
    "changes": [
        {
            "rev": "4-773re8f44e"
        }
    ],
    "deleted": true
},
{
    "seq": "18-g1AAwe_g",
    "id": "ewf/34r",
    "changes": [
        {
            "rev": "9-wehch87ewc"
        }
    ],
    "deleted": true
}],
"last": {
    "last_seq": "21-g1AA8wd998rAQ",
    "pending": 0
}
```